# How to create a billing alert/alarm to notify AWS data transfer limit?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to create billing alert for AWS resources when we cross some specified cost/data limit.

Comment: I don't believe that is possible in a simple and straightforward way to monitor only data transfer charges, since data transfer is aggregated across regions and services, has many different pricing tiers, and is not exposed as a single metric... you may need to enable -- then parse -- the daily billing estimates file... but perhaps we'll get a useful answer, here, with something I haven't considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS Management Console has the ability to create [budgets and forecasts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/budgets-managing-costs.html) for expenditure and usage of AWS services.

[image: AWS Budets and Forecasts]

Email alerts can be configured when the forecast or actual spend passes particular proportions of the budget (eg 50%, 80%, 100%).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example CloudFormation resource to create a billing/budget alert.

```
  Resources:
    MonthlyBudget:
      Type: "AWS::Budgets::Budget"
      Properties:
        Budget:
          BudgetName: Monthly
          BudgetType: COST
          TimeUnit: MONTHLY
          BudgetLimit:
            Amount: 100
            Unit: USD
        NotificationsWithSubscribers:
          - Notification:
              NotificationType: ACTUAL
              ComparisonOperator: GREATER_THAN
              Threshold: 80 # 1st alert sent when % of Monthly total is spent.
            Subscribers:
              - SubscriptionType: EMAIL
                Address: email@example.com
          - Notification:
              NotificationType: ACTUAL
              ComparisonOperator: GREATER_THAN
              Threshold: 95 # 2nd alert sent when % of Monthly total is spent.
            Subscribers:
            - SubscriptionType: EMAIL
              Address: email@example.com
```